# No suitable constructor found while trying to populate the listview

Tags: android, listview

Im trying to load datas from sqlite db to a listview.

Following is my piece of code that I use to populate the list view

```
List allPendingOrders = notificationDbHandler.getInstance(getActivity().getApplicationContext()).getAllPendingOrders();

ListView mListView = (ListView) mRootView.findViewById(R.id.list);
ArrayAdapter adapter = new ArrayAdapter(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, allPendingOrders);
 mListView.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Following is the error message that Im getting,

```
Error:(180, 76) error: no suitable constructor found for ArrayAdapter(<anonymous Listener<JSONObject>>,int,List)
constructor ArrayAdapter.ArrayAdapter(Context,int,int,List) is not applicable
(actual and formal argument lists differ in length)
constructor ArrayAdapter.ArrayAdapter(Context,int,List) is not applicable
(actual argument <anonymous Listener<JSONObject>> cannot be converted to Context by method invocation conversion)
constructor ArrayAdapter.ArrayAdapter(Context,int,int,Object[]) is not applicable
(actual and formal argument lists differ in length)
constructor ArrayAdapter.ArrayAdapter(Context,int,Object[]) is not applicable
(actual argument <anonymous Listener<JSONObject>> cannot be converted to Context by method invocation conversion)
constructor ArrayAdapter.ArrayAdapter(Context,int,int) is not applicable
(actual argument <anonymous Listener<JSONObject>> cannot be converted to Context by method invocation conversion)
constructor ArrayAdapter.ArrayAdapter(Context,int) is not applicable
(actual and formal argument lists differ in length)
```

Comment: Probable Creating object of `ArrayAdapter ` in Fragment so use `getActivity()` instead of `this` as first parameter to `ArrayAdapter ` constructor

Comment: yeah thank you let me try that...

Comment: that works but it displays something like `com.model.PendingOrdersDao@4331589`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this

```
ArrayAdapter adapter = new ArrayAdapter(getActivity(),android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,android.R.id.text1, allPendingOrders);
```

mListView.setAdapter(adapter);
You are missing id of textview 
Refer here for more detail: -https://coderzpassion.com/android-working-with-listview/

Comment: that works but it displays something like `com.model.PendingOrdersDao@4331589`

Comment: @Stanly you need to pass string for this if you are passing certain objects then implement using CustomAdapter Refer here for detail:- http://coderzpassion.com/android-listview-with-image-and-text/

Comment: sure Let me try that out

Comment: @Stanly let me know if you have any problem. Thanks

Comment: thank you. I have created the custom adapter. Im not sure how to use it within onCreateView method. I have to loop through db and add all contents to myItems then I have to setAdapter. But, Im facing complication while doing so,,

Comment: @Stanly Give a try if u have any problem then we can figure out.

Comment: `java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'int android.view.View.getImportantForAccessibility()' on a null object reference` is the error message being thrown

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/104960/discussion-between-jagjit-singh-and-stanly).

Answer (score 0):

Your this parameter in your constructor is pointing to a listener and not to the activity you are using it in. Try with

```
      ArrayAdapter adapter = new ArrayAdapter(YourActivityName.this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, allPendingOrders);
```

In case you are using adapter in afragment you can go with ρяσѕρєя K suggestion.